# where to add the c sharp code in this example to make changes in sharepoint programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint

i am trying to programmatically do some changes in sharepoint as per the link below

in the link below there is a the second cod snippet is a C sharp code. where do i put this code ? or how can i use this code in sharepoint is not mentioned .. can anyone please tell me ?

http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/03/05/select-multiple-list-items-in-sharepoint-feature.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried any of the code out in the post you linked to, but it looks like the C# code just needs to be compiled into an assembly and deployed to the SharePoint server.

The `<CustomAction>` element in the feature XML below the C# code references this assembly via the `ControlAssembly` attribute and the compiled class is referenced by the `ControlClass` attribute.

If you're adapting the code in the post and creating your own project, ensure that your assembly and class names are correctly referenced in the feature XML file (through the `ControlAssembly` and `ControlClass` attributes).

Alternatively you can download the author's [SharePoint Solution Pack](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/04/21/downloadaszip-sharepoint-feature-rtw.aspx) which contains this feature and others.

Answer (score -1):

you should create a new program to call the method